# When can $this reference variables outside its class in PHP?

Tags: php, scope, this

```
class A {
  public function f(){
    $this->ar[0] = 'something';
  }
}
```

For example, how can function f be called such that $this->ar will refer to an array declared outside of class A? Assume that A is not inheriting ar.

Edit:

I tried to simplify the question. The actual code I'm looking at is
the function `index` in opencart's [ControllerStartupStartup class](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/admin/controller/startup/startup.php)
The function index is using $this to access class instances that aren't defined in that class: `$this->db`,`$this->config`, and `$this->tax`.

They are not declared in the parent class [Controller](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/engine/controller.php) either.

The function is being called with `call_user_func_array(array($controller, $this->method), $args);` in the [Action](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/engine/action.php) class.

Comment: It simply can't, as `$this` refers to an `A` instance

Comment: Well I guess my example is oversimplifying something. I'm looking at [an opencart controller](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/admin/controller/startup/startup.php) I don't know how it is accessing `$this->config`. It is being called like with `call_user_func_array` inside of [this](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/engine/action.php)

Comment: It is extending the class [Controller](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/engine/controller.php), but that class also does not have that variable defined there.

Comment: That controller has ['magic' properties](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html).

Comment: OK thanks! I will learn about that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make "ar" known and provide it in the class as setter, so the instance ar is known and you can address it with $this

```
class A {
  $ar = array();

   public function f(){
     $this->ar[0] = 'something';        
   }
 }
 // INSTANCE with Setter
 $ar[0]='whatever';
 $class = new A();
 $class->ar = &$ar;
 $class->f();
 echo $ar[0];
```

Comment: But you are declaring the variable inside of A. I added links to the code I'm looking at. Sorry if I oversimplified my question.